# how to make from,to(two) value mysql limit query in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, eloquent, limit

i need to make from,to(two) value mysql limit  query in  laravel 5
how to convert this query in Laravel query given bellow
SELECT * FROM  `games` LIMIT 5 , 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`take()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries) and [`skip()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries):

```
User::skip($from)->take($to)->get();
```